# Hiding title bar in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show or hide a title bar on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394197/show-or-hide-a-title-bar-on-demand)

is it possible to hide the tittle bar completely in winform application.different forms?????

i don't want to hide only minimize and maximize button but want to hide total title bar in forms.
is it possible if yes than how 
Plzz help me i am new in winform application....

Comment: Just leave the Title aka Text empty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read our faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions. The wrath you're incurring is because the answer to this question is easily derived from a simple web search using obvious keywords (e.g., hide title bar windows winforms, etc.). Your colleagues here are eager to help solve your problems -- provided you've demonstrated an effort on your part as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm almost certain this has been asked/answered over 9000 times, but the simplest way is to remove the window border in it's entirety.

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Assuming this code is in a method on your form
```