# Strange effect of the form minimization in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my own minimize button with the following code on the `Click` event:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.notifyIcon.Visible = true;
```

Sometimes when I click on it, the form appears in the left bottom corner of the screen like this:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a counter-measure against you setting ShowInTaskbar to false. The user won't be able to restore it so Windows makes it a minimum size window instead of hiding it.  Otherwise without paying attention to the fact that you've prevented that from working as well by making it a borderless window.

You need to call Hide() instead.

Comment: So it is ok to just call methods Hide and Show instead of ShowInTaskbar and WindowState, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413938/hiding-title-bar-in-windows-form-application) link

you need to add

`this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`

to your minimization event.

Comment: But I've already set this property to `None` in the designer. Is it not enough?